# Integration by parts including delta function

Tags: calculus, integration, measure-theory, definite-integrals, dirac-delta

Often in physics we integrate by parts $$\int_{x_0}^{x_1} f(x) \frac{d}{dx}( \delta(x-y))dx$$

by:

$$=[f(x) \delta(x-y)]_{x_0}^{x_1} - \int_{x_0}^{x_1} \delta(x-y) \frac{df}{dx} dx$$.

I have a really simple question, how can we assume that $[f(x) \delta(x-y)]_{x_0}^{x_1}=0$?

Intuitively the delta function is zero except for at $x=y$, but what if either $x_0$ or $x_1$ was equal to y?

Is the answer simply 'we must assume separately that $x_0,x_1 \neq y$, or is there something obvious that I'm missing, or is there some measure theory reason why we can say it is zero?

Comment: Typically this result is used when $x_1,x_2$ bracket $y$. In the case where one of them is equal to $y$ your concern is warranted.

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue is mostly one of notation.  The delta function is actually a distribution. If $a \in \mathbf R$ and $f$ is a smooth compactly supported function then $\delta_a(f) = f(a)$.

The derivative of a distribution $T$ is *defined* to make the integration by parts formula work. That is, $T'(f) = -T(f')$ for any smooth compactly supported function. In the particular case of the delta function you get $$\delta_a'(f) = - \delta_a(f') = - f'(a).$$

People have found it notationally convenient to denote $\delta_a(f)$ using the notation
$$\delta_a(f) = \int f(x) \delta_a(x) \, dx = \int f(x) \delta(x-a) \, dx$$ and similarly
$$\delta_a'(f) = \int f(x) \delta_a'(x) \, dx = \int f(x) \delta'(x-a) \, dx.$$

Thus by definition $$\int f(x) \delta'(x-a) \, dx = \delta_a'(f) = - \delta_a(f') = - \int f'(x) \delta(x-a) \, dx.$$

Comment: Does all this assume integrals over the whole real line, rather than definite integrals?

Comment: The integral is over the domain in question. Since $\delta'$ is a distribution it acts on functions compactly supported in that domain.